# angularjs selft $broadcast and $on

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I have created custom directive something like drop down but in my case items open in modal popup and after selection item will selected in div.

Now I added two directive (**i.e. two instance of same directive**) and using this two directive work as parent child way. I am getting item from rest api then assign to first directive(**i.e. parent**) and based on selection of first directive I am filtering another rest api then assign to second directive (**i.e. child**) which is working very good. But I wanted to reset value (selected item) of  the second directive whenever change selection on first directive.

I added below code to my directive but it did not help me

```
controller: ['$scope', '$rootScope',
        function($scope, $rootScope) {
          $scope.$watch('value', function(val) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('valueChanged', $scope.id);
          });
          $scope.psChanged = function() {
            $scope.$on('valueChanged', function(event, value) {
              if (value === $scope.id) {
                //Do nothing.
              } else {
                console.log("Text change");
              }
            });
          }
        }
      ]
```

`My full working plunker`
http://plnkr.co/edit/f6LYS2aGrTXGkZ3vrIDD?p=preview

Can somebody help me to get it done !!

Comment: I would do it in different way. Add one more attribute for the directive to watch. (so you need to use '=' , 2 way binding) if the value of this observed attribute is changed, clean the value of itself. This way you don't need to use event. After all, it is just an one to one communication, I won't use event for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added one more attribute in isolated scope, called isChild, when it`s true im listening for event valueChanged. So i bind even listener in controller without function psChanged, and it works.

```
angular.module('plexusSelect', []).directive('plexusSelect', ['$ionicModal', '$timeout', '$ionicScrollDelegate', '$rootScope',
  function($ionicModal, $timeout, $ionicScrollDelegate, $rootScope) {
    // Runs during compile
    return {
      scope: {
        'items': '=',
        'id': '@',
        'text': '@',
        'textIcon': '@',
        'headerText': '@',
        'textField': '=',
        'valueField': '@',
        'callback': '&',
        'isChild' : '@'
      },
      require: 'ngModel',
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'plexusSelect.html',
      controller: ['$scope', '$rootScope',
        function($scope, $rootScope) {
          $scope.$watch('value', function(val) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('valueChanged', $scope.id);
          });
          if ($scope.isChild === 'true') {
          //$scope.psChanged = function() {
            $scope.$on('valueChanged', function(event, value) {
              if ($scope.id === value) {
                //Do nothing.
              } else {
                $scope.clearSearch();
                $scope.value = '';
                $scope.text = $scope.defaultText;
                console.log("Text change");
              }
            });

          }
        }
      ],
```

html

```
<ion-view view-title="Search" ng-controller='SearchCtrl'>
    <ion-content>
    <h1>Search</h1>
  <plexus-select id="psDeparture"  is-child='false' items="deptStations" header-text="Select Departure Station" text="Select departure..." text-icon="icon-takeoff" text-field="['City_Name_EN','City_Code']" value-field="City_Code" ng-model="deptStation.value"></plexus-select>
    <plexus-select id="psArrival" is-child='true' items="arrStations" header-text="Select Arrival Station" text="Select arrival..." text-icon="icon-landing" text-field="['Destination.City_Name_EN','Destination.City_Code']" value-field="Destination.City_Code" ng-model="arrStation.value"></plexus-select>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

[plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/2ODElkmhLuiv2xdCsqRE?p=preview)

Comment: The if statement in the event listener callback was doing the 'isChild' check already. The only problem with the code was how the event listener was wrapped in `$psChanged`. Either way this is a solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. It works good. But I have one issue, when I added 1 another directive which is not a child and also nor parent, I wanted that directive to act as alone but still when I change the value of that directive my child directive become blank, are we missing something. I think can we pass id of the depended directive  What do you say